# Unable to set path for activator file

Tags: java, playframework

How do I set path in a mac after downloading activator zip file for play framework ? I have unzipped the file in my Documents folder , but on running the commands **activator ui** or **activator new** from the terminal , it gives command not found error. I am running the command from the documents folder , to which I have the write access. Should I run the command from some other location ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Installing it by home brew makes things a lot easier.
Type the following in the terminal -

1. $brew install typesafe-activator
2. $activator ( this will activate the activator)
3. $activator new